# Invalid BusinessColumnName while creating row in n:n table

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

i get error while using associate method:
Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException:

> OrganizationServiceFault: Invalid BusinessColumnName Guid value =  for PlatformName = new_AccountingLevel and objectId = 1aa032d5-02cb-ed11-99b5-005056b20412 --->

i'm trying to add a row in a n:n table in dynamics in my plugin here is my code:

```cs
var accountingLevel = _client.new_AccountingLevelSet.FirstOrDefault(al =>
    al.new_AccountingLevelId == new Guid("1AA032D5-02CB-ED11-99B5-005056B20412"));

var relationship = new Relationship(new_new_cash_box_new_accountinglevel.EntityLogicalName);

_context.Service.Associate(new_cash_box.EntityLogicalName,
    target.new_cash_boxId.Value, relationship,
    new EntityReferenceCollection
    {
        new EntityReference(new_AccountingLevel.EntityLogicalName,
            accountingLevel.new_AccountingLevelId.Value)
    });
```

I checked and I'm sure both target and accountingLevel is not null. I also tried using target.Id and accountingLevel.Id and I also tried this one:

```cs
_context.Service.Associate(new_cash_box.EntityLogicalName,
    target.new_cash_boxId.Value,
    relationship,
    new EntityReferenceCollection
    {
        accountingLevel.ToEntityReference()
    });
```

These are my n:n table columns: `new_accountinglevelid`, `new_cash_boxid`, `new_new_cash_box_new_accountinglevelId`

The relationship itself is working fine. I tried it by adding item from subgrid.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```cs
var relationship = new Relationship(new_new_cash_box_new_accountinglevel.EntityLogicalName);
```

The entity logical name is used instead of the intersect's schema name. Often they are the same, but they may differ.